# What does PST mean?

Tags: terminology

I've seen on the internet, on several sources ([here](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Slang/PST.html) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/534914-/56397948) are just a couple of examples) that "PST" means "Please Send Tell". But the sentence "please send tell" doesn't make any sense to me.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what the first game to do this was, but a "tell" is a private message sent to another player. I think it originates way back from [text-based MUDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) where to message someone you'd type something like `tell <name> <message>`.

These days many multiplayer games call those messages "whispers" instead, but often `/tell` will be aliased to it. For example, in World of Warcraft you can message someone either via `/w` for "whisper" or `/t` for "tell".

So, "please send tell" basically means "contact me privately to respond".

Comment: Probably in those MU*s you didn't even use a / - the parser always expected every line to begin with a command.  There was no 'default chat' or anything like that.  A consequence of being purely text-driven, of course - modern MU*s aren't really much different.

Comment: Plus "pssst" is the sound of a whisper :)

Comment: @Shinrai Yeah, good point. Man, it's been a while. :) I amended my answer slightly.

Answer (score 3):

Another meaning is "Pacific Standard Time," a time zone eight hours west of Greenwich, used by places like Los Angeles (movies, games,) San Francisco (start-ups, games) and Seattle (Microsoft, games.)

If you're talking about scheduling of events, then this is a much more likely meaning of the acronym.